# Lubuntu didn't upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: lubuntu

I am very much a Linux novice, but while exploring Lubuntu off and on for a couple of months I was given the option to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS which I did.  After several hours of the upgrade, I still have Lubuntu on my computer but the System details indicate Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.  Is it possible to upgrade from Lubuntu to the newest Ubuntu?

Comment: 16.04.1 is the latest LTS release.  Are you asking how to upgrade to 16.10?

Comment: Lubuntu is a flavor of Ubuntu, i.e. Ubuntu with some modifications.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of Lubuntu and go back to Ubuntu?